# How to make a clone of the object class System.Windows.Documents.Run?

Tags: c#

I have a class object System.Windows.Documents.Run, I need it to copy. There are options other than manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization is a common way to clone an object (if you don't want to code it manually) - is is serializable? (or: could it be?)

This has the advantage of being a deep clone and maintenance-free, but is slower (*how much* slower depends on the serializer chosen).

Note: if you choose to use `BinaryFormatter`, make sure you mark any events as `[field:NonSerialized]`. `BinaryFormatter` isn't my *preferred* serializer, but it is acceptable for in-memory cloning purposes (and is simple to get working - just mark your types as `[Serializable]`).

Comment: Thanks. Serialization has helped me